# Flutter FCM on resume on launch and on message not working in ios missing plugin implementation is triggered when launch

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Flutter FCM on resume on launch and on message not working in ios missing plugin implementation dart service  is triggered when launch , working fine on android
The following is the code used to handle fcm .In IOS notification is triggered when app is in background and when clicked application is opened

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print(message);
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
            new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
        // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
        var initializationSettingsAndroid =
            new AndroidInitializationSettings('launcher_icon');
        var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
        var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
            initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
            onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
        var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
            '123', 'convoy notification', 'convoy notification',
            importance: Importance.Max,
            priority: Priority.High,
            ticker: 'ticker');
        var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
        var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
            androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0,
            message['notification']['title'],
            message['notification']['body'],
            platformChannelSpecifics,
            payload: message['data']['payload']);
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        var string = message["data"]["payload"];
        var payload = jsonDecode(string);
        print(payload);
        if (payload != null) {
          var type = payload["refresh"];
          if (type == "OFFERS") {
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
              _navigateToOffers(payload["id"]);
            });
          } else if (type == "REQUESTS") {
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
              _navigateToRequests(payload["id"]);
            });
          }
        }
        //_navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        var string = message["data"]["payload"];
        var payload = jsonDecode(string);
        print(payload);
        if (payload != null) {
          var type = payload["refresh"];
          if (type == "OFFERS") {
            _navigateToOffers(payload["id"]);
          } else if (type == "REQUESTS") {
            _navigateToRequests(payload["id"]);
          }
        }
        // _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
  }
```

Comment: Having same issue. Any luck on this ?

Comment: Till now issue is unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete these lines in your ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift :

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate }
```

I get the same problem, and after removing this code my app works well.